# Вывод порядковых номеров массива

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Вроде бы простой вопрос - вывод порядкового номера
элементов массива в Angular. Делаю так, но получаю ошибку:

```
<li *ngFor="let i of this.countStr">
  {{i}}
</li>

Тип 'number' не может быть присвоен типу 'NgIterable <any> 
| null | неопределенный'

i у меня типа number, объявлена в файле .ts: i: number = 0;
Если тип number указать вместо var - тоже не катит.

Может для кого-то это не есть проблемой, но всё-же просьба 
помочь, т.к. с Angular только начал разбираться.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36354365/4711135

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема связана с тем, чтобы вы пытаетесь передать не массив, а число.

Для того, чтобы ваш пример заработал нормально, нужно, чтобы `countStr` был массивом, а не числом.

Текст ошибки говорит, что число не может быть итерируемым типом. То есть по нему нельзя пройти циклом.

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any>'.
```

В Angular нет built-in директивы, которая может выводить данные в цикле по числу.

```
<li *ngFor="let number of 5">{{number}}</li> // здесь будет ошибка
```

```
<li *ngFor="let number of [0,1,2,3,4]">{{number}}</li> // должно быть так
```

Если у вас массив объектов и их номер не указан в качестве поля объекта, то можно использовать index для вывода.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">{{i}}</li>
```

Подробнее можно почитать в [документации](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)